# is there anything like _VIewEnd?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have a javascript file that I have included in _ViewStart.cshtml like below but I want it to append in the end of view.

```
@if (!Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/example.js")"></script>
}
```

There is no layout to the view if its ajax call and there are alot of views which I will have to change if there is not simple way of appending this js file in the end of view.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't currently have a layout for mobiles then you could introduce a new layout:

**_Layout.Mobile.cshtml:**

```
@RenderBody()
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/example.js")"></script>
```

MVC4 will recognise the .Mobile part of the layout name and use that for mobile devices.

And then your **_ViewStart.cshtml** will simply be:

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }
```